# fetch data from mysql table and display

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to fetch image name stored in database and display it but it is not working? Can anyone please tell me what is wrong in below code:

```
<p class="phase-title-en">
<?php 
 $title="SELECT DISTINCT record_step_one FROM phase_one_data";

 $vartitle=$dbh->prepare($title);
  $vartitle->execute();
  $result= $vartitle->fetch();
  ?>
   </p>
   <?php foreach($result as $fn_title) { 

    echo "<p>  '".$fn_title['record_step_one']."'</p>";
    }
    ?>
```

My database looks like this:-
[image]

Comment: What about it isn't working? Have you checked for errors?

Comment: You can just print_r($title); what you get?? And also print_r($result); ok

Comment: And you should read this [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) regarding the *please answer as soon as possible*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that you are using the PDO `fetch()` method, which returns only the next row of the result set (in your case, the first row).

This way, when you do a `foreach`, you are actually iterating over the columns of your first row (and not over all the rows, as you intended).

So your code is probably throwing lots of error messages (actually E_NOTICES) telling you that you are trying to use a string as an array, because each of the values in the loop (`$fn_title`) are strings containing the values for the first row (5, 2, eagle, etc).

*EDIT*: Sorry, but in my original reply I didn't notice the DISTINCT keyword in your query. So actually, the foreach would run only once, and the value would be the string `eagle`. But still, the problem is the same, there is no index `record_step_one` inside the string `eagle`.

The first step towards your solution would be to replace `fetch()` with `fetchAll()`, and check for any other errors that may arise (for instance, we can't see where `$dbh` is being instantiated in your code, which may or may not be a problem).

Comment: $dbh is not an problem its a global variable. now about fetch() and fetchAll() i tried both but still its not working.

Comment: can you please just edit my code n past over here so i ll be able to understand properly what you mean to say

Comment: If you replaced fetch() with fetchAll() you are already one step closer to the solution. Edit your question with the response/errors that you are getting, so I might help you more.

Comment: there is no error msg now its displaying all the data from the database

Comment: but i want specific one

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve. Some screenshots of your output would certainly help. What your code is currently doing is fetching all the distinct (unique) values of column record_one_step from the table phase_one_data. So if you have 3 rows, with the values (eagle, eagle, dolphin) you would get the following output: eagle, dolphin.